# How to incorporate artificial variables into the revised simplex method

Tags: simplex

Seems like we can convert `>=` constraints to `<=`, either by multiplying by -1 or using variable substitution. But for `=` constraints, seems like we need artificial variables.

How do we incorporate artificial variables into the revised simplex method?

Comment: What problem formulation are you trying to apply the simplex method to? The most common is to minimize c^T x subject to Ax = b and either x >= 0 (simple) or l <= x <= u (advanced). Neither case needs artificial variables for equality constraints? Maybe you are asking for help with simplex phase 1 (seeking feasibility)?

Comment: to get an initial feasible basis, you may need artificial variables, isn't that right? Imagine you had 3 `=` constraints, there would be no slack/surplus variables, and 3 artificial variables?

Comment: Practical revised simplex algorithms don't need artificial variables. They can handle infeasibilities.